# Why function does not giving response from php file to android activity?

Tags: php, android, function, android-activity

I'm new in android development, actually i want to create login system. I have researched about it and find a function, which is working properly for posting data. I sure data is successfully submit on php file. Now i want to get response from same function, i have tried so far but unable to get result. Please view my code and help me where i wrong or what should i do many thanks.

### Android Code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";
    private EditText editEmail;
    private EditText editPass;
    TextView resultView;
    private TextView status,role,method;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Button loginButton;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);


        editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
        editPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
                final String pass = editPass.getText().toString();
                //perform action
                if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                    editEmail.setError("Please enter valid Email...");
                }
                else if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                    editPass.setError("Please enter valid Password");
                }else{
                    resultView.setText("submited");
                    new PostDataGetRes().execute();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                }


            }
        });



    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

 public class PostDataGetRes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {

           postRData();


            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
            // do stuff after posting data
        }
    }
    public void postRData() {
        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        final String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
        final String pass = editPass.getText().toString();
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/appservice.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", pass));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            //resultView.setText("Inserted");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();

            //convert response to string
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                isr.close();

                result=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
            }

            //parse json data
            try {
                String s = "";
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    s = s +
                            "Name : "+json.getString("first_name")+"\n\n";

                    //"User ID : "+json.getInt("user_id")+"\n"+
                    //"Name : "+json.getString("first_name")+"\n"+
                    //"Email : "+json.getString("email")+"\n\n";
                }

                resultView.setText(s);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
            }

       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        resultView.setText("Done");
    }
}
```

### Php Code

```
$id   = $_REQUEST['id'];
if($id){
        $query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '$id' ");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $selectedData[]=$row;
        }
        print(json_encode($selectedData));
    }
```

Comment: On a side note: Avoid using the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Yes I know I will use mysqli_* thanks

Comment: Why not directly connect to the database instead of doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to update the UI from the doInBackground method which actually doesn't run on the main thread, what you need to do is make the doInBackground return the text you want to put in the TextView and THEN update the textView in the onPostExecute method.

```
public class PostDataGetRes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            return postRData();


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // do stuff after posting data
        resultView.setText(result);
        //Change text to done after 0.5 seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                resultView.setText("Done");
            }
        },500);
    }
}
public String postRData() {
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    final String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
    final String pass = editPass.getText().toString();
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/appservice.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", pass));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //resultView.setText("Inserted");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result=sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try {
            String s = "";
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s +
                        "Name : "+json.getString("first_name")+"\n\n";

                //"User ID : "+json.getInt("user_id")+"\n"+
                //"Name : "+json.getString("first_name")+"\n"+
                //"Email : "+json.getString("email")+"\n\n";
            }

            return s;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Always handle any changes that you need to do to the UI from the main thread.

Comment: `return postRData();` due to this android studio giving me error `Error:(140, 33) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String`

Comment: Thats because the function postRData() wasnt returning String all you had to do was change the return type of the function from void to String, I have edited in the changes to my answer